# Typescript define class type without defining a JS class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create a class type for classes with certain properties. E.g.:

```
class Cat {
  name = 'cat';
}

class Dog {
  name = 'dog';
}

type Animal = ???;

function foo(AnimalClass: Animal) {
  console.log((new AnimalClass()).name);
}
```

I want `doSomething` to accept any class that has a string `name` property. The only way I could do this is:

```
class _Animal {
  name: string;
}

type Animal = typeof _Animal;
```

Is there a way to do this without defining a new JS class? I just want the type.

Comment: Interfaces aren't compiled to javascript, and ideally to be used for intellisense. That's the best option. A drawback is that on creation, you have to explicitly define all properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can describe constructor using `new` expression:

```
type AnimalContructor = new () => { name: string };

function foo(AnimalClass: AnimalContructor) {
  console.log((new AnimalClass()).name);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYBdoG8CwAoa0B2YC2AptALzQDkwiZA3BgL4YaiQwAiA9gOYoZa6ElyAEy416jdAgCeAByIBBbAEs8YELHbYEAJwCuwBO22DsBAO7QAFAEoSAPhQ58BAFzQIOpdm51a6DABmutgGSprQAezslooqarDgUG6xquqaOvqG2rZomNDAmhDsIAQAdCBclpamFinxiRA21qX8BNZ+DP7okdEcnNYSzFDQAEJgxsidgVGWY9kSQA)

---

Other option is defining union of constructors:

```
type AnimalContructor = typeof Cat | typeof Dog;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYBdoG8CwAoa0B2YC2AptALzQDkwiZA3BgL4YaiQwAiA9gOYoZa6ElyAEy416jdAgCeAByIBBbAEs8YELHbYEAJwCuwBO22Dpc9gDM4iaAB9opghegdOtdBnO7sBpZujn2dgAKRRU1WHAoAC5oUNV1TR19Q20ASh5MaGBNCHYQAgA6EC4goOwCAHdY5XiIliDU1IL%20AlS3Bnd0AOCXVIlmKGgAITBjZA6PQKCRtIkgA)

Comment: With the `new () => {}` syntax, is it possible to use `extends`? E.g. if `Dog` and `Cat` both extend a third-party library class, I want `Animal` to extend the same class. I tried something like `type AnimalConstructor = new () => { name: string; prototype: Foo.prototype };` but that didn't work

Comment: Yes, you can use [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) for this `type AnimalContructor = new () => { name: string } & Foo;` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoa0BmiBc0AdgK4C2ARgKYBO0AvNAKwDcGAvhhqJDAMJgAXaJQAeAyoQAmMBEjSYiYUpXrQA5MEFrW6Dui7go0ACLwA5sLETpcRCgxZCSlQzWTz29p3QCAngAcVAEFCAEtSMBBeeEIBamJgAXhaBkJKAHdoAAoASnoAPhRFZQIIONDCCzZoADJbeB0MbGJCRNCYnEQskPDI3kMIAh6IqJi4hKTqPPksYBiIeBBKADoQcyystMzhvoHcnOXceBydNiA

Comment: Nice, Five Answers! with respect 

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use generics here. I create a type that I make this type to be only assignable to object with name property as a string, and then I add a generic type that extends Animal type. This way you don't have to create a new class for Animal.

```js
class Cat {
  name = "cat";
  age = 2;
}

class Dog {
  name = 'dog';
}

class Car {
  brand = "Audi";
}

type Animal = {name: string};

function doSomething<T extends Animal>(animal: T) {
}

doSomething(new Dog());
doSomething(new Cat());
doSomething(new Car()); // typescript error car is missing name
```

And if you would like to make Animal type extend another class you can use intersection

```js
class Cat {
  name = "cat";
  age = 2;
}

class Information {
  year = 2020;
}
class Dog extends Information {
  name = 'dog';
}

type Animal = { name: string } & Information;

function doSomething<T extends Animal>(animal: T) {
}

doSomething(new Dog());
doSomething(new Cat()); // typescript error cat is missing year
```